# Date format in doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I have the following field of an entity:

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="upload_date", type="datetime", nullable=true, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $uploadDate;
```

I want to insert the upload date with php. The statement which would do that is:
`$flyer->setUploadDate(new \DateTime("now"));` but its doesn't work and given error is:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "format" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update with your controller and the rest of the entity?

Comment: I think you have a problem in different place. You have an instance of UploadedFile class somewhere and you are trying to call a format method which obviously doesn't exist there. Check the trace and post a part of the code where this error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you in your Entity constructor to do like this. This will set current date to your property automatically when the entity will be created.

```
public function __constructor()
{
    $this->uploadDate = new \DateTime();
}
```

Comment: Nothing. Error is the same.

Comment: plz provide code of your Entity and where do you use it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a set function for your UploadDate field. Your entity code must be like this

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="upload_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $uploadDate;

.... more code ....

public function __construct()
{
    $this->uploadDate= new \DateTime();    
}
```

When you create a new object in the controller you don't need to call

```
$flyer->setUploadDate(new \DateTime("now"));
```

Detele the function setUploadDate() in your entity. The construct function set the uploadDate. Now you can call to:

```
$flyer->getUploadDate();
```

Comment: @AxeOwl Did this answer help you? Did you try this solution?